# Image slider is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I have done an image slider but this is not changing the images, just showing the first image.

This is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#images .image');
  var current = 0;


  function nextImage() {
    image[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
    current = (current+1)%images.length;
    images[current].className = 'image show';
  }
  var Interval = setInterval(nextImage,2000);
});
```

html:

```
<ul id="images">
    <li class="image show">Slide 1</li>
    <li class="image">Slide 2</li>
    <li class="image">Slide 3</li>
    <li class="image">Slide 4</li>
    <li class="image">Slide 5</li>
</ul>
```

I am using jquery 3.1.0 and it is not working

Comment: First thing move function `nextSlide` out of document.ready

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: why you needed currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length; ? can't just currentSlide = currentSlide+1; would work for you? might be you will have to check number of slides condition outside though

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use `#slides > .slide` as a selector instead?

Comment: In console I am getting TypeError: slides[currentSlide] is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code and it seems to work fine, apart from the unecessary call to `nextSlide()` near the end of document ready. Perhaps it's your CSS? Please run this working code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var slides = $('#slides .slide');
 var currentSlide = 0;
 var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, 2000);

 function nextSlide() {
  slides.removeClass('showing');
  currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % slides.length;
  slides.eq(currentSlide).addClass('showing');
 }
});
```

```css
.slide {display:none;}
.showing {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="slides">
    <li class="slide showing">Slide 1</li>
    <li class="slide">Slide 2</li>
    <li class="slide">Slide 3</li>
    <li class="slide">Slide 4</li>
    <li class="slide">Slide 5</li>
</ul>
```

I have removed mixed vanilla JS and used jQuery to keep things more consistent.

Some other things to check as the Javascript may not be running at all:

- Check for errors in the console
- Check you are linking jQuery properly (before your code, script tags parsed and executed from top to bottom in order unless you specify otherwise)
- Make sure you have only one `$(document).ready` per page.

Comment: Not that it matters, and is certainly not my place to say this, but you should never remove vanilla js in favor of jQuery.... it is de-optimizing the code, especially in these one liners.

Comment: Yes, but if the OP is using jQuery already then they may as well use it for this purpose.

Comment: I am using jquery  3.1.0 and it is not working for me

Comment: I have updated the snippet to use the same version of jQuery. There must be something else causing it to fail for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your js code bit, you can give a try with this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
  console.log(slides);
  var currentSlide = 0;
  var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,2000);

  function nextSlide() {
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
    currentSlide = currentSlide + 1;
    if (slides.length == currentSlide) {
       currentSlide = 0;
    }
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
  }
  nextSlide()
});
```

Comment: Yes somewhat correct but also please notice I have added statement currentSlide = currentSlide + 1; before this condition so even length-1 would not work